Who should the moderators be?
As stated here about a week or two into the public beta, three candidates will be appointed moderator pro tempore.
This is a thread to nominate such candidates.
Nominees should:

Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in 
everything they write.
Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

with bonus points for 

Participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building 
and expertise in the field).
Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
Having already shown an interest or ability to promote the community.

Each nomination should be posted in a seperate answer, including a link to the user profile (parent and meta) and links to other activities (e.g., Area 51, blogs or other resources announcing/reviewing the community).   
If the nomination is done by a 3rd-party, the nominee should edit the answer and state whether he accepts the nomination, preferably also writing something about them self.
A nomination should be marked community wiki, such that potential new nominees with low reputation may edit the post.
Self nomination is okay and even encouraged. This is a way of saying “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.”

Any nominations posted here should be made CW so that the nominees can themselves edit in their responses. Comments are not the best place for accepts/declines as they may get hidden over time.

@AshRj might help to explain what is "CW" and how to do it...

@IgorSkochinsky CW means community wiki. These posts are editable by anyone. Edits made are directly published without going through any review. An answer can be made CW by selecting the small tick option just below the answer body on the left. https://i.sstatic.net/TU52N.png For more see the  CW-FAQ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

*not left, but right

Oh I see. Well, I can edit posts even if they are not community wiki.

You need a certain reputation to do so, as there are no suggested edits on meta. Which could potentially make some nominees unable to edit the post.

I strongly vouch for Igor Skochinsky.
The amount and quality (in both length and details) of his answers speak for themselves.
It might sound redundant as he's already the moderator of r/ReverseEngineering, but I don't see anyone more qualified and showing more dedication.
EDIT: Hi, Igor here. Here's my card.

profile for Igor Skochinsky on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/185833.png

I like answering stuff more than policing it so I was hesitating, but I'll accept the nomination, at least for now. As has been mentioned, I'm a mod of the RE subreddit, together with Rolf (Syzygy here). I also follow tags like "disassembly" or "reverse-engineering" on SO and am trying to give good answers there. I work at Hex-Rays on IDA and the decompiler and also do quite a lot of RE as a hobby so I encounter RE problems every day. I'll try to not be biased towards my company's products but I guess some of it will be unavoidable so keep that in mind when voting. I'm also pretty new to the moderation/meta side of SE.

I definitely agree.

+1, I agree. Hope it won't be too biased towards IDA, though. As indispensable as it is, there are other tools.

Thanks for the vote of confidence! I'm trying to be unbiased but I can only speak of what I have experience with :)

You should make this a CW so that @Igor's acceptance can be added to the post

@Igor, as per the guidelines, you ought to edit the post and "introduce" yourself. As it seems that you accept the nomination.

@IgorSkochinsky Not suggesting you spam every one. More important than having lots of users, is having active users. (With some participation on Meta as well.)

+1 / top candidate!

I would also like to nominate Peter Andersson. The reasons should also be obvious from the answers and conduct.
profile for Peter Andersson on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2516828.png

Obviously a very intelligent and considerate guy, +1.

I absolutely agree. +1
